# Do any skills apply from characters not active in the party?

Tags: tales-of-arise

Obviously, skills like "+10% attack" on an accessory or "Increased Maximum AG" from the skill panel, only affect that character. But there are skills like Kisara's "Easier Party Member Over Limit", or accessories with "Rare Drop Rate Up", or even Spirit Bangle accessories with "Recover 1 CP on Enemy Defeat". Do any of these apply if they're on a party member who isn't in the fight? The in-game help menu is pretty thorough, but doesn't seem to address this.